# Stop animation in UICollectionView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation

I have a timer that fires every second to refresh data on a `UICollectionView` cell, sometimes (especially when I rotate the device), the cell starts to blink every second.  I want to stop this blink animation.  However, I have another animation going on inside the collection view cell, so I don't want to disable all animations on it as this code does:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}];
```

Comment: Can't you refer to the animation via the key paths and simply remove it?

Comment: @Mundi Ah, yes I can!  What's the value of the key path string for the dissolve animation for the cells?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want animation on reloading collection view, why don't you just call

```
[collectionView reloadData];
```

It only reloads all visible cells.

For the animation inside of the collection view cell, why not code more in the cell object?